# How can I dynamically resize elements and sibling elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, resize

If you take a look at emmawatson.com or ted.com, you will notice that there are multiple panels, or divs, that resize on hover.

At emmawatson.com, they actually cause the other divs to dynamically resize based on the div being hovered over.

I would like to create a similar effect, using click, for divs within a certain boundary.

How can this be done?

The psuedo code is as follows:

```
$(div*containing"input").function()
div*containing"input".resize(when input element is active)
otherDivs.move(get out of the way so this div can expand)
$(xButton).click(bring things back to their original size)
```

Don't make fun of my pseudocode. I am brand spanking new to this. :P

http://jsfiddle.net/JVtyv/9/

Comment: i don't see it on ted.com and emmawatson.com is flash... do you have another example?

Comment: Basicly you need a float optimizer like isotope or using absolute positioned divs, for that to happen without bugging. A simpler approach would be something like http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-feature/

Comment: @TimJoyce I want that flash effect using a jQuery solution. And I am fine with doing a TED like effect, in which the div expands, and the others maintain their same dimensions, but lower in opacity. I am going to make it an onClick function. When clicking one of the input elements, the div that contains it will resize.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen that is an oversimplified version of what I want to do sort of. If you account for the fact that the divs do not have the same dimensions and there are divs below, left, right, and above certain elements that would have to resized accordingly, it becomes much more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look at jquery isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html. This plugin recalculates element layout when you change the size of an element in the selection as well as making many other element layouts solutions elegantly simple.

It should do exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: Yes yes yes!! That is exactly what I am looking for! Now I just need to figure out how to actually use it and apply it to my design. Thank you so much! If you get the chance, please offer some guidance about actually incorporating into my own design. Again, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hover()` method in jQuery to do this.

The hover method works like so: hover(over, out); insert functions that you want to take place for "over" and "out" and you're set.

So if you wanted to resize the images inside a div like on emmawatson.com you would do something like the following using the hover and css methos:

```
 $(function(){
$("div").hover(function(){
    $("div img").css({"height":"150%" , "width":"auto"}); //auto scales the width according to the image height
    },
    function(){
        $("div img").css({"height":"auto" , "width":"auto"}); //auto resizes image back to default dimensions
        });
});
```

Just use some CSS like `overflow:hidden;` to clip the image inside the div and you're good to go.

Also, make sure to read up on the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). It does wonders!

Comment: My answer is similar to what is being done on the non-flash pages of emmawatson.com. The homepage for that website uses flash.

Comment: I understand that I can resize a single element using the hover effect and some basic css, but the problem is that I would be looking at creating a function for divA to resize to a certain width onClick and change the sizes of divB, divC, divD, divE, and divE. Then I would write another function to resize divB onClick, and change the sizes of divA, etc. This is impractical to write a long function for each separate div. Check the link to the fiddle and you will see the impracticality of this method, unless I am misunderstanding it. Thank you! :)